# Is it worthwhile merging these interfaces if their contents are the same because of c# Generics?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a repo for companies and users but the interface to them is the same

```
  public interface ICompanyRepository
    {
        void RollbackChanges();
        void SaveChanges();
        IQueryable<T> Set<T>() where T : class;
    }
  public interface IUsersRepository
    {
        void RollbackChanges();
        void SaveChanges();
        IQueryable<T> Set<T>() where T : class;
    }
```

do you think its worthwhile combining them into a single class ie IRepository

```
 public interface IRepository
        {
            void RollbackChanges();
            void SaveChanges();
            IQueryable<T> Set<T>() where T : class;
        }
```

Comment: Yes, its commonly known as the Generic Repository Pattern. When combined with IoC its quite effective

Comment: Same exact interface twice and you are asking if you should make it all one interface?  What exactly am I missing here?

Comment: @kd7 cool I invented something! sometimes I feel I'm just creating to wrappers around my .net DbContext..

Comment: After reading this http://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton I am temped to bin the repo and use the context directly. What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, move the common functionalities to a common interface. It'll reduce duplication in your code.

Answer (score 1):

It makes no sense to have two separate interfaces that are identical for something that is the same concept.

Yes - merge them. You will have a single place to make changes when needed, following the [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).